# How do I restore a dialog window when neither a taskbar button nor systray icon available?

Tags: windows-xp

When I use my TWAIN scanner from within Photoshop, it launches a non-modal dialog (or frame, I'm not sure) with the scan options.

I just minimized this window because it was in the way, but I cannot restore (unminimize) it. It doesn't have a task bar button or a system tray icon, and it doesn't show up in Alt+Tab.

I know it's not closed because when I go to the TWAIN menu option in photoshop, it's still grayed-out. I've made several adjustments in the scanner dialog that I don't know out of my head and I don't want to lose either.

I've also tried the un-minimize shortcut Win+Shift+M, but that only seems to work after a Win+D or Win+M command.

Comment: And then I found it the solution. I found a little Windows 3.11-style minimized window in the lower left of the screen just above the start button, when I have photoshop on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will help in your particular situation, but sometimes I find [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) useful as it can show list of processes with corresponding main windows with `Ctrl+W` and one can activate selected window by hitting `Enter`.

If you don't feel like installing Far Manager, I believe other applications that show more windows than Task Manager will do the trick. Probably [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) will work if you happen to have it installed.

Comment: +1 but how will Spy++ work if you cant drag the target onto a invisble window? @Zom-B By show more windows than Task Manager you can see programs like ProcessMonitor.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Indeed I completely forgot about Sysinternals.
It was quite a while since I ever used Spy++. I remember there used to be a comprehensive list of all windows (including children). I believe there is a way to search for the proper one. As I said I use Far Manager and List of Processes (`Ctrl+w`). It may help or may not in this case, but it does show some stuff that I can't access otherwise. The benefit of Far is that it is a good file manager as well ;-)

Comment: woops I meant Process Explorer not ProcessMonitor.

Comment: I used Process Explorer, and sadly the TWAIN window doesn't show up as a process. It is simply a thread in Photoshop. And again, I'm positive the TWAIN window isn't closed, as when I thought I had given up and I wanted to close photoshop, it complained that a TWAIN acquire session is still running.

Comment: Furthermore, launching a second photoshop and trying to access TWAIN gives me an error that it is unavailable at the moment.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson: Although your solution didn't work in my case, it is the general and best solution to the question stated in my title. If you make it an answer I'll mark that one as correct instead.